# Unable to add products to Cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

After using shortcode `[add_to_cart id="09"]` for ex. "**Read More**" button is displayed, instead of "**Add to Cart**".

What shall I do to make it "Add to Cart" so that my product gets added to cart. I remember my client wasn't interested in having add to cart button.

To solve his problem I included "Read More" button and directed the flow to single product page. Now I want to include "Add to Cart" button to add products to cart, however it is showing "Read More", instead of "Add to Cart".

Please help me solve the problem

Comment: From what I can understand, if you changed the default "Add to Cart" behavior to a "Read More" behavior through hooks/actions or even altering the source code, you need to revert that implementation.

Comment: Your question is unclear as it depends **on the product type**… You can use `[add-to-cart]` Shortcode **on simple products** for example to get an "Add to cart" button feature… If not "Read more" is displayed (like for variable products).

Comment: Thanks, I used the theme 'shopisle' theme, and on every product displayed on that theme had "Add to cart" button displayed on hover. I changed the name to "Read More" and directed the behavior to the respective product page (visit url - http://handmhomeco.com/product-category/bowls/). I was interested in restoring the behavior to "add to cart" again, I wasn't getting, how to restore?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you could use the shortcode [add_to_cart].

But you can also create your own button by using a custom Add to Cart URL.

To create a custom Add to Cart URL for that product, you will need to add ?add-to-cart=123 replacing 123 with the ID of your product.

The result will be something like https://www.yourwebsite.com/?add-to-cart=123. Whoever clicks on this link, will add the product 123 to their cart.

**To begin, open your dashboard and go to Products.**

In the products’ list, hover over the product you want to create a custom Add to Cart URL for. On the left, you will notice a text like ID: 123 where 123 is the ID of that product.

Comment: Thanks, I used the 'shopisle' theme, and on every product displayed on that theme had "Add to cart" button displayed on hover. I changed the name to "Read More" and directed the behavior to the respective product page (visit url - http://handmhomeco.com/product-category/bowls/). I was interested in restoring the behavior to "add to cart" again, I wasn't getting, how to restore it back?